# Regex to capture 2 consecutive digits, but don't capture if 3 or more

Tags: java, regex

For example.
If I have 
`1234X03.04`

I want to capture the `03` and `04`
But I don't want `12`, `23`, `34`

I understand:

- negative lookahead: `(?!...)`
- negative lookbehind: `(?<!...)`

But, I don't know how to combine that into a single regex.
Can someone help me out? Cheers.

Comment: Oh well done. Thanks. If you put that as an answer I'll accept. (MonkeyZeus)

Comment: Could you describe the rules better? is it allowed to do this without regex? Just pure java?

do you want to capture the numbers after the x but only if at maximum 2 numbers exist?

Comment: I don't care about the Java side so much - can map that - so as long as it flies on regex101.com I can handle the rest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)
```

- `(?<!\d)` - prior char is not a digit
- `\d{2}` - exactly two consecutive digits
- `(?!\d)` - next char is not a digit

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/c2OWte/1) of the results in PHP. I think PHP's regex is close to Java's.

Comment: Does this work on the trailing `.04`? is the `end of the line` covered by the last part of the regex?

Comment: @f1sh I supplied a demo.

Comment: Note: [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/) has the Java dialect, but PHP should be OK for most cases

Comment: I was going for `(?<=^|\D)\d\d(?=\D|$)`, but the supplied answer works just fine with less steps.

Comment: @RenatoBack There's always more than one way to achieve the same thing in programming :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need `(?<=\D|\b)\d{2}(?=\D|\b)`

`(?<=\D|\b)\)` - not digit or a word boundary before our expression but without including it in the match.

`\d{2}` - our expression, only two digit, including it in the match.

`(?=\D|\b)` - not digit or a word boundary after our expression but without including it in the match.

Comment: Can you please try to explain the regex?